# Creating polygon from hole in polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, polygon-creation, holes, ring

I work with this polygon and try to find a way to create a new polygon from the empty gap (not distinguish it) in the middle of the polygon.

I succeed to do it with the "Difference" tool but used with another layer on the polygon and then using the difference tool.

I can also digitize the shape of the hole and create a new layer I seeking an automated way to do it and not doing in manually.

I read:

- ["Clip" hole into Shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216439/clip-hole-into-shapefile?rq=1)
- [Create Polygon from holes in polygon ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252827/create-polygon-from-holes-in-polygon-arcgis?rq=1)
- [How to fill in ring polygon in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89571/how-to-fill-in-a-ring-polygon-in-qgis-2-2)

Is it possible to do it with a direct tool in QGIS 2.18.1, without the aid of another layer?

[image: example]

Comment: Manually for this one hole? Or for a whole layer with holes?

Comment: for the whole layer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fill in a ring polygon in QGIS 2.2?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89571/how-to-fill-in-a-ring-polygon-in-qgis-2-2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend [Digitizing Tools](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DigitizingTools/) plugin.

[image]

Once installed, you will find a new toolbar. The eighth from the left of this toolbar, there is an icon called `Fill ring with a new feature (interactive)`.

For you to fill all rings at once;

1. Switch to **Fill all rings in selected polygons with new feature** mode by clicking on a small triangle (right-hand-side).
2. Start editing mode and select polygons you want to work on (you can select all polygons).
3. Click on the tool icon.
4. A small dialog box will appear and asks you to give a new attribute value. This value will be given all fillings, so that it helps you to identify these new features in the attribute table. Hit `[OK]` to close.

Comment: Plugin tools are not active @Kazuhito

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS I can suggest using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume there is a layer *'layer_with_holes'* with its corresponding attribute table, see image below.

[image: input]

There are possible two cases.

---

**Case I.** When holes that are located on the polygon edges should not be included.

With the following query, it is possible to create a new polygon layer from the empty gaps inside the polygons.

```sql
-- generate series
WITH RECURSIVE generate_series(cat) AS (
SELECT conf.start
FROM conf
UNION ALL
SELECT cat + conf.step
FROM generate_series, conf
WHERE cat + conf.step <= conf.stop
),

-- config
conf AS (
SELECT
1 AS start,
1 AS step,
SUM(st_numgeometries(st_difference(make_polygon(st_exteriorring(l.geometry)), l.geometry))) AS stop
FROM "layer_with_holes" AS l
)

-- query
SELECT cat, st_geometryn(st_union(st_difference(make_polygon(st_exteriorring(l.geometry)), l.geometry)), cat) AS geom
FROM generate_series, "layer_with_holes" AS l
GROUP BY cat
```

The output Virtual Layer with its Attribute table will look as follows.

[image: output_1]

---

**Case II.** When holes that are located on the polygon edges should be included.

With the following query, it is possible to create a new polygon layer from the empty gaps within the polygons.

```sql
-- generate series
WITH RECURSIVE generate_series(cat) AS (
SELECT conf.start
FROM conf
UNION ALL
SELECT cat + conf.step
FROM generate_series, conf
WHERE cat + conf.step <= conf.stop
),

-- config
conf AS (
SELECT
1 AS start,
1 AS step,
SUM(st_numgeometries(st_difference(make_polygon(st_exteriorring(l.geometry)), l.geometry))) + st_numgeometries(st_difference(make_polygon(st_exteriorring(st_union(make_polygon(st_exteriorring(l.geometry))))), st_union(make_polygon(st_exteriorring(l.geometry))))) AS stop
FROM "layer_with_holes" AS l
)

-- query
SELECT cat, st_geometryn((st_union(st_union(st_difference(make_polygon(st_exteriorring(l.geometry)), l.geometry)), st_difference(make_polygon(st_exteriorring(st_union(make_polygon(st_exteriorring(l.geometry))))), st_union(make_polygon(st_exteriorring(l.geometry))))), cat) AS geom
FROM generate_series, "layer_with_holes" AS l
GROUP BY cat
```

The output Virtual Layer with its Attribute table will look as follows.

[image: output_2]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the trace tool (on the Snapping Toolbar) and simply trace around the hole in the polygon while creating a new feature in a new layer (or your existing layer).

[image]

Comment: i don't want to digitize by manual- i search for automatic action.

Comment: where the trace tool location?

Comment: on the Snapping toolbar - look at the one I have ringed in red

Comment: your image is too small

Comment: if you click on it it will get bigger

Comment: where i can find it in http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/     ?

Comment: it is a tool bar - so no not in plugins. Right click on a grey area and select it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88332/discussion-between-newgis-and-ian-turton).